# how to have multiple relations between two models in django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

im new to django and was trying to create models for a youtube like website.
im trying to create models such that a user has record of:

1) playlists he has uploaded.

2) playlists he has viewed. i tried the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
name=models.CharField
email=models.EmailField
password=models.CharField
isTeacher=models.BooleanField
upvotes=models.IntegerField

class Playlists(models.Model):
creator=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
viewed_by=models.ManyToManyField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name=models.CharField
size=models.IntegerField
```

i hope you get what i want to do. obvoiusly this scheme doesn't work. but i want to do something on similar grounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *can* work, but you need to specify different values for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name), this is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so you can construct such model with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Playlists(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='created_playlists'
    )
    viewed_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='viewed_playlists'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    size = models.IntegerField()
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).